# Google AI Platform _InactiveRpcError, MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

Trying to run:

```
client = google.cloud.aiplatform.gapic.JobServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
client.create_custom_job(parent=PARENT, custom_job=CUSTOM_JOB)
```

I got:

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Received http2 header with status: 404"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1623698785.509643000","description":"Received http2 :status header with non-200 OK status","file":"src/core/ext/filters/http/client/http_client_filter.cc","file_line":130,"grpc_message":"Received http2 header with status: 404","grpc_status":12,"value":"404"}"
>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Alright I changed the region from `eu-west2` to `eu-west4` and it worked, it seems this was not implemented yet in that region although the docs mention otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to modify the region from `eu-west1` to `europe-west1`